# Jenkins startup process: how delete or fix warning messages

Tags: jenkins

When I execute:

```
java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=9090
```

For `2.25` version, the app starts up and works fine but I did realize in the terminal/console always appears these two warnings:

```
Main deleteWinstoneTempContents
WARNING: Failed to delete the temporary Winstone file /var/folders/nf/ql69b5zd7w54jw6nb5zmvck80000gn/T/winstone/jenkins.war
```

and

```
org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog warn
WARNING: Empty contextPath
```

How I can fix them? Even when they are `warnings`, I want remove them.

For the first, yes, I've confirmed the path only exists until `/var/folders/nf/ql69b5zd7w54jw6nb5zmvck80000gn/T/`, the rest `winstone/jenkins.war` does not exist.

Why does the second appear?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue.But i fixed it.Please download apache-tomcat-8.5.16 or the latest one.Run the startup.bat file and type http://localhost:8080/ and you will see Apache Tomcat up & running on your local host.

Now run java -jar jenkins.war and type http://localhost:8080/jenkins/ and jenkins will be up and running on your local host.

Hope it will solve your issue.

Comment: You can also start jenkins (standalone) on different port                            run java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=9090

Comment: Is just a warning, is not critical. be aware both can't use the same port. Therefore `--httpPort` is mandatory

Answer (score -3):

Corrected Command:

```
java -jar jenkins.war -httpPort-9090
```